# How to increase wait time of speech recognizer between input of first and second word

Tags: android, speech-recognition

I am using Google speech recognition for speech recognition.Is there any way available in which I can increase the wait time of speech recognizer.

For example - If I say "good" and then wait for 2 seconds and then say "morning",then output should get recognized in combine like "good morning" together instead of first "good" and then "morning".

I know about method - "EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS", but it is used before speaking any word

Thank you.